# Fade in on switching classes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am sure my problem is pretty easy to solve. I want to apply fade in when my header became visible and fadeout when it isn't visible. So i don't want to be that rough. I tried with  `header.removeClass('clearHeader').addClass("darkHeader").fadeIn(slow);` but that didn't help me. I also tried to add transitions in CSS but that didn't help me too.

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
    //caches a jQuery object containing the header element
    var header = $(".clearHeader");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 50) {
            header.removeClass('clearHeader').addClass("darkHeader");
        } else {
            header.removeClass("darkHeader").addClass('clearHeader');
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
 header {
  width:100%;
  height: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index:999;
  background-color:#fff;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
header nav {
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    line-height:70px;
    }
header nav a {
    margin-left: 25px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 18px;
    }
header nav a:hover {
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px red;
    }
.clearHeader{
    display:none;
    opacity:0;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.darkHeader {
    display:visible;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:999;
}
```

[**CODE PEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjKbma)

Comment: it is empty codepen

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjKbma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try by remove opacity and display visible code from css and try fadeIn and fadeOut Like:

```
if (scroll >= 50) {
    header.removeClass('clearHeader').addClass("darkHeader").fadeIn('slow');
} else {
    header.removeClass("darkHeader").addClass('clearHeader').fadeOut('slow');
}
```

Comment: I remove opacity from darkHeader but not from clearHeader and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you can simply use jQuery's `animate`. [Here's the syntax and explanation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). It smoothly animates any css property you would want to animate. Therefore you can do:

CSS:

```
header {
    opacity:1;
}
```

(just sets the default)

JS:

```
header.animate({opacity: "0"}, 500);
```

To fade out, and the same thing but with opacity 1 to fade in. You may want to comment out the display part of your classes for testing though, as it may influence how it all behaves.